# How to restrict email domains in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a question regarding firebase authentication. Actully I am making a dashboard for my company, and I will host it in firebase. I want to restrict the email authentication only to my comany domain (ex: cat.com). But I went through the stackoverflow answers and I found I can impose rule in database. But the issue is that I will be calling external databases to fetcj data using Firebase Function and serve it to website(dashboard). So no domain specific rule will apply there. Below is the outline of my dashboard architecture

[image]

How can I achieve this? I want people having "xxxx@cat.com" will be able to autheticate and view dashboard data

Comment: This question is not well written. What do you mean by 'I want people having "xxxx@cat.com" will be able to autheticate'? It would be helpful to get more information

Comment: Does your company use GSuite and would they login with Google or is it email-pass login?

Comment: @BenButterworth suppose our company has people named Tom, James & Harry Their email id will be Tom.surname*cat.com, James.surname*cat.com etc. I don't want people with *gmail, *outlook etc not able to sign up. Since a valid email with domain google or outlook should not view my company data (* stands for at the rate)

Comment: @frunkadno we have custom domain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Case 1:** The user has already created their account, and you want to restrict one cloud function to specific email addresses.

You can get the user info associated with the cloud function call, and check their email. You can then call the external database if they have the correct email domain. You should also do some UI changes so the user doesn't just get errors if they don't have `@cat.com`.

---

**Case 2:** Restrict all users in your Firebase project to emails containing `@cat.com`?

If so, you can't restrict the emails directly in firebase authentication, so you'd have to stick user registration code behind a cloud function, creating user accounts there. You can then check their email when they try to register.

You can do this with the Firebase Admin SDK in a cloud function. [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: 'user@example.com',
  emailVerified: false,
  phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
  password: 'secretPassword',
  displayName: 'John Doe',
  photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
  disabled: false
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

The client will call the cloud function with their desired email and password, and before calling this `.createUser`, and you can check for the correct email before creating the user with `"dog@cat.com".toLowerCase().endsWith("cat.com")`.

---

Alternatively, you can set a custom claim for users as mentioned by @frunkad: Give extra permissions to users who register with "@cat.com" emails, and this is shown here: [Defining roles via Firebase Functions on user creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#defining_roles_via_firebase_functions_on_user_creation). However, in OP's case, only users with "@cat.com" should be able to register, so custom claims are over-complicating the issue.

Also, using email domain as a form of access control doesn't sound like a good idea. During the account creation process, you manually add access to the user's document based on the email. What happens when you want to give someone an email but don't want to give them access to the database?

Comment: seconds option sounds okay. Actually all of the users having the email domain will have access to all the services.

Comment: Great, but in the long term, you might want to add alice@dog.com to the access list, and prevent eve@cat.com from the access list. But I might be adding a feature you don't need :)

Answer (score 34):

## If your company uses GSuite & logins via 'Login With Google'

Firebase's Google Login is built on top of normal Google Logins + a lot of automation. Among these is the part when they create a new [OAuth 2.0 Client in GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials). This would be named `Web client (auto created by Google Service)`

[image: Web Client]

This client is auto-linked to [OAuth Consent Screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=) where you can mention your App's Display Name **and limit it to users in your organization with a Google account**

[image]

## If your company uses Email & Password login

The easiest method is to immediately check for organization email via firebase background [auth trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) `onCreate` as mentioned in Ben's answer. If the account does not belong to your organization - delete it immediately.

This would tho *for a brief moment* give access to your system to the malicious user. To further protect, you can set [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to your organization user (when they register - in firebase function) & make sure every request to firestore/real-time database has those custom claim checked. **Similarly you can check for custom claim in firebase function before making call to your database**

Comment: This should be the correct answer @Void95

Comment: @cereallarceny only if your company uses Gsuite.

Comment: `background auth trigger onCreate mentioned in Ben's answer`. I actually meant using a HTTP cloud function in my answer. Auth triggers (deleting a user immediately when creating) for this purpose will allow **catastrophes** in the future. What if the delete fails for some reason (not all http requests succeed)? The user will have full access for eternity because the trigger happens only on deletion and creation. You could argue, anything can fail like this, but this failure is much worse than if a HTTP cloud function simply doesn't run: worst case is the user gets back a 500 and gets no data.

Comment: `This would tho for a brief moment give access to your system to the malicious user.` Basically, by doing this, you are doing 2 things wrong: You let your threat-actor/ hacker create an account on your system. And, you decouple your steps (user creation looks like you're letting all users in, and somewhere else in your code base, user deletion is deleting them) which makes it even harder to spot for developers. You shouldn't be creating an account for your threat-actor at all. PS: Some smart developer might come in the future and say, hey we have this delete function but all our users are @cat

Answer (score 9):

In your firebase security rules just paste this

this works for me and I am able to restrict logged in Google user to my org domain

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email.matches('.*@domain[.]com');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer and would expand it by also adding some UI logic that tells the user they aren’t authorized and attempt to redirect them. Then the security rules on the database to enforce that they can’t access any data.

Answer (score 4):

As of August 2022, you can write [blocking functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events) that can stop a user from creating an account if some requirements are not met.  The linked documentation specifically shows this example:

> ```
> export const beforecreated = beforeUserCreated((event) => {
>   const user = event.data;
>   // (If the user is authenticating within a tenant context, the tenant ID can be determined from
>   // user.tenantId or from event.resource, e.g. 'projects/project-id/tenant/tenant-id-1')
>
>   // Only users of a specific domain can sign up.
>   if (user?.email?.includes('@acme.com')) {
>     throw new HttpsError('invalid-argument', "Unauthorized email");
>   }
> });
> ```

Use of blocking functions requires that you use [Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform).