# Allow Firebase authentication only from specific domain

Tags: security, firebase-authentication

I'm relatively new to Firebase and sometimes run into confusion.
Since you have all the configuration information in the frontend, anyone could take this data and build their own registration page. How can I prevent this and limit registration requests (via email and password) to one domain?

Searched docu and stackoverflow without any success -.-

Comment: In general, you can't restrict cloud service to a particular app on a web domain because there is no way you can validate that any given request is actually coming from that domain.  All you can really do is make it harder for attackers to do what they want by obscuring any sort of entrypoint or protocols.  You might want to consider looking into [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) to add a layer of protection.

Comment: If you are asking how to restrict email signups to a particular email address domain, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62977597/how-to-restrict-email-domains-in-firebase-authentication

Comment: If theres no way to restrict it, how can it be good practice to set all the Firebase config settings into frontend code? with that everyone can build his own registration page. So i guess i have to do everything with firebase functions to keep the settings hidden?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public